# React JS- merge index 1 of array 1 with index 1 of array 2

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to merge index 1 of array 1 with index 1 of array 2 in react JS but I am not sure how to create the loop in app.js to show the firstname+lastname of each person.

```
    //App.js

import React from 'react'; 
import Names from './Test.js'; 
import Lastname from './Lastnames'; 
class App extends React.Component {
render() {
let names = ["Lucy", " ",  "Kaity", " ",  "Maria", " ",  "Barbara"];
let lastname = ["Stone", " ",  "Black", " ", "Rodriguez", " ",  "Pitt"];
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Names names = {names}/>
    <Lastname lastname = {lastname}/>
  </div>
);
} }
export default App;

Test.js

import React from "react";
class Names extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <span>{this.props.names}</span>;
  }
}
export default Names;

//Lastname.js

import React from "react";
class Lastname extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <span>{this.props.lastname}</span>;
  }
}
export default Lastname;
```

Thank you so much :)

Comment: What should the exact output be? `Lucy Stone, Kaity Black,` etc... ?

Comment: Can you share how output should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi sorry the question was little unclear to me, so I will try to answer what I understand.

If you want to combine two arrays you can use Javascript map function to achieve this.

```
  let namesCombined = names.map((currentName, index, arr) => {
    return `${currentName} ${lastname[index]}`
  });
```

Your full code looks like this -

```
//App.js
import React from 'react'; 
import Names from './Test.js'; 
import Lastname from './Lastnames'; 

class App extends React.Component {

render() {
  let names = ["Lucy", " ",  "Kaity", " ",  "Maria", " ",  "Barbara"];
  let lastname = ["Stone", " ",  "Black", " ", "Rodriguez", " ",  "Pitt"];

 // assuming you are using ES6 syntax
  let namesCombined = names.map((currentName, index, arr) => {
    return `${currentName} ${lastname[index]}`
  });

  // at this point namesCombined will have both first name and last name combined.

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Names names = {names}/>
      <Lastname lastname = {lastname}/>
    </div>
  );
```

Again sorry this is how I understood your question. If you can show how the output should look like, I can fix my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I meant to present the name+last name <3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge two arrays based on their index you can use javascript `Array.map()` function:

```
  const fullnames = names.map((name, index) => {
    `${name} ${lastnames[index]}`
  });
```

and you can use `for`:

```
const fullnames = []
  for(var i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
   fullnames.push(`${names[i]} ${lastnames[i]}`);
  }
```

you don't need to save space in your arrays.

I didn't find out what you want for the result but in case of merge, you can use the above code.

also, you can use const instead of let.

Comment: Thank you, guys! The idea was indeed to have the names presented as Lucy Stone, Kaity Black, etc :)